# VPN tunnel router behind router

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec

Is it possible to make VPN tunnel where VPN router is behind main router?
R2 is VPN server and PC 192.168.1.20 is VPN client
If yes, please tell me how.

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use forward VPN port from R1 to R2. 
For example in OpenVPN you must forward TCP/UDP port which U set in config file (port 1194 in default) from R1 to R2.

But not in all types of VPN this will work. 
For example PPTP protocol uses port 1723 and GRE, and it will be useless to forward port 1723 to PPTP server on R2.